# Mapping an array within an array with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to get some map over some data and render it as a card style component.

The data structure is as follows within my user array (all fake data)

[image: screenshot of dummy data]

and this is the code...

```
import React from "react";
import OverlayContent from "./OverlayContent";
import { onCountryClick } from "../Scene3D/AppSignals";
import Portal from "./Portal";
import "./style.scss";

class Overlay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { overlay: false, users: [], country: [] };
    this.openOverlay = this.openOverlay.bind(this);
    this.closeOverlay = this.closeOverlay.bind(this);
  }

  openOverlay() {
    this.setState({ overlay: true });
  }

  closeOverlay() {
    this.setState({ overlay: false });
  }

  onCountryClick = (country, users) => {
    this.openOverlay();
    this.setState({ users: [users], country });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onCountrySignal = onCountryClick.add(this.onCountryClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.onCountrySignal.detach();
  }

  render() {
    const country = this.state.country;
    const users = this.state.users;

    console.log(users);
    return (
      <div className="btn-container">
        {this.state.overlay && (
          <Portal>
            <div>
              <h1>{country}</h1>
              {users &&
                users.map(user => (
                  <div className="user_container">
                    <h1 key={user.id} className="user_name">
                      {user.favouriteQuote}
                    </h1>
                  </div>
                ))}
              <button className="btn" onClick={this.closeOverlay}>
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </Portal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Overlay;
```

When mapping on this user array it doesn't appear to give me access to the actual user data I need. Is it because I have an array within an array?

Comment: Seems like you want to map `users.users`

Comment: you missing a return for map

Comment: Also note that from the data you posted it doesn't appear that you have the "id" field you use as key, but just a "name" field.

Comment: @DennisVash I thought so too but when I do ``` {users.users.map(user => (``` I get Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Is this because it's an object rather than an array?

Comment: Please fix your question, how do the users really look like. If you can't copy-paste try adding a screenshot of the console.

Comment: I think if you just remove the brackets here `this.setState({ users: [users], country });` and change to `this.setState({ users: users, country });` it will be a single array instead of an array inside an array and it will work. Are you needing it to be nested?

Comment: `this.state.users[0].users` - You should fix it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
 onCountryClick = (country, users) => {
  this.openOverlay();
  this.setState({ users: [users], country });
 };
```

Is users an array? If so remove the brackets here or map through the first element. `users[0].map()`